# Debo/puedo copiar mi respuesta de una pregunta que cerraron a otra pregunta no cerrada similar?

Tags: discusión, respuesta

Buen día comunidad de SOes Meta!

Básicamente lo que refiero en el título, tengo esta respuesta de mi autoría en la siguiente pregunta que fue cerrada: [¿Libreria PDF para PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170954/libreria-pdf-para-php/170961#170961) y hoy leyendo me encuentro con esta otra pregunta (que no parece que tener motivos para que sea cerrada): [¿Como generar reportes pdf en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/173617/como-generar-reportes-pdf-en-php/173721#173721). Entonces me surgió una duda importante sobre como tratar estos casos?

Debo colocar un comentario la referencia a la pregunta que fue cerrada donde está mi respuesta válida? o sencillamente puedo copiar mi respuesta a la pregunta nueva? La he copiado ya pero no sé si esté bien la acción o por el contrario deba revertirla.

He notado que la han puntuado positivamente y colocado como favorito así que dudo que esta pregunta nueva la cierren.

Muchas gracias de antemano por su colaboración

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Una pregunta basada en opiniones no se ajusta bien al [formato y contenido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) del sitio, debe cerrarse como basada en opiniones y **[no responderse](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Eso aplica a las dos preguntas enlazadas. Que tenga una mejor recepción no quiere decir que deba mantenerse abierta.

El hecho de que esté pidiendo recomendaciones y ejemplos sin aportar nada, debería hacer sonar alguna alarma en los usuarios. Si lo hiciera de otra manera, quizás sí se ajustaría mejor al formato del sitio (p.e. "*Estoy buscando una librería que genere pdf, he probado ABC pero no puedo hacer XYZ porque LMN, ¿que me recomiendan?*" es una pregunta pidiendo recomendaciones pero aportando conocimiento y quitando parte de la subjetividad: no se pide una librería sin más, se ha hecho una investigación previa, se han hecho intentos y hay unas condiciones que deben darse... se busca algo específico y con experiencia.)

Además, hay otra cosa que debería hacer sonar las alarmas y es copiar una respuesta de una pregunta a otra. Si una misma respuesta sirve para dos preguntas, eso normalmente quiere decir una de dos cosas:

1. Las preguntas son la misma: en cuyo caso la más nueva (que no debería tener respuestas) debería votarse como duplicada de la otra.
2. La respuesta es demasiado genérica o amplia y aplica a dos preguntas diferentes: en cuyo caso las respuestas debería editarse para hacerse más concretas y que no sean iguales.

De hecho, **copiar respuestas de una pregunta a otra se considera negativo** y hace sonar las alarmas: los moderadores recibimos una notificación automática indicándonos las dos respuestas y pidiendo que las revisemos para tomar una acción y ponernos en contacto con el usuario.

Sobre cómo debería actuarse en ese caso: podrías dejar un comentario enlazando a la otra pregunta como sugieres, y definitivamente debería votarse por cerrar, bien como duplicado o bien como basada en opiniones. Pero no responder, y no copiar respuesta de una pregunta a otra.

Comment: Ok. Inmediatamente elimino la respuesta y reporto como basada en opiniones. Aunque suene tonto prefiero preguntar para no equivocarme. Muchas gracias

Comment: Ya eliminé la respuesta y reporte la pregunta nueva. Ahora dejo comentario haciendo referencia a la pregunta anterior cerrada, quizás le aporte algo al OP de la nueva pregunta que están por cerrar

Comment: En el caso concreto de esa pregunta que comentan (y yo también pensé que era una pregunta algo genérica al inicio hasta que me documenté)...  ¿cuantas librerias/funciones para crear PDF a partir del contenido de una WEB hay en PHP?... ¿realmente es una pregunta tan genérica o imprecisa o de poca utilidad para la comunidad? ... Tengo dudas al respecto.

Answer (score 2):

Las respuestas que han ofrecido son muy ilustrativas respecto a ¿Qué y cómo preguntar? y, me afectan un poco en lo personal porque recuerdo haber recorrido los foros buscando una manera razonable para generar pdf desde php, particularmente para un aplicativo en producción que debía enviar pdf de resumen de actividades a los usuarios de la biblioteca de una universidad a la que le hice un módulo en Drupal para manejar todos sus procesos de circulación, préstamo, catalogación etc.

Recuerdo haber recorrido cuanto foro conocía (leyendo preguntas afines) y haber consultado wikis, Dr. Google, repositorios (sourceforgue, github) hasta que por fin pude dar con una sugerencia orientadora. El problema de fondo con esas búsquedas es que muchas veces conducen a bibliotecas privativas y finalmente, la gente acaba por preguntar.

Cuando se tiene la experiencia de haber perdido muchos días buscando en situación similar, uno piensa: "¿no es, acaso, el sentido de la educación o de compartir conocimiento, ahorrar tiempo a los demás, para que vayan más lejos que a dónde yo pude llegar?" Y, claro, obrando en consecuencia se ofrece respuesta.
Más aún, no puedo contar las veces en que he encontrado las sugerencias o las ideas valiosas para lo que he sido capaz de hacer en preguntas cerradas de algún foro.

Planteo esta acotación, porque creo importante y pertinente que se reflexione el asunto. Alguien puntuó positivamente la respuesta de @huskie, y la discusión me hizo recordar experiencias de búsqueda difíciles. Recuerden que no se va a los foros porque se sabe, quienes venimos acá, **lo hacemos porque ignoramos** y cuando percibimos que podemos aportarle algo a alguien que está tropezando dónde nosotros lo hicimos, le ayudamos a ver la roca.

Comment: Hola quevedo. Muchas gracias por tan valioso aporte. He entendido con la pregunta que realicé aquí que el chat disponible en StackOverflow serviría para estas preguntas abiertas a opiniones que cite en la descripción de la duda planteada. Claro que los usuarios nuevos sabrán poco de las reglas del sitio e incluso puede que ignoren totalmente que existe un chat.